# Django 1.1.1: How should I store an empty IP address using PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am writing a Django application that stores IP addresses with optional routing information.  One of the fields for the IP model I have created is `nexthop` (for next-hop routes), which will usually be empty.  Originally we intended to use MySQL, but now project requirements have changed to use PostgreSQL.

Here is a stripped down version of my model:

```
class IP(models.Model):
    address = models.IPAddressField()
    netmask = models.IPAddressField(default='255.255.255.255')
    nexthop = models.IPAddressField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    active  = models.BooleanField('is active?', default=1)
```

So, with MySQL I did not have a problem leaving the `nexthop` field empty. However, now that I switched the development environment to Postgres, we've run into a [known issue in Django 1.1.1](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5622) in which a blank IP address raises a `DataError`

```
invalid input syntax for type inet: ""
LINE 1: ...-14 13:07:29', 1, E'1.2.3.4', E'255.255.255.255', E'', true)
                                                             ^
```

As you can see, it bombs because it is trying to insert an empty string when the column will only accept a `NULL`.

I have a very real need to be able to keep this field empty, because if an IP doesn't have a next-hop, then its behavior changes.

Short of hacking the Django code manually, which is my ultimate last resort, I have also thought of defaulting next-hop to 255.255.255.255 and wrapping some business logic around that (i.e. If next-hop is 255.255.255.255, treat as normal route), but that just feels like a hack.

I would like to know if there are any suggestions on a better way to do this that would not require hacking Django or writing hacky logic, or if there is a completely different approach altogether that can satisfy my requirement.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Interim Solution**

For the time-being (as an interstitial fix) I decided to go with the sentinel value for the next-hop:

In the model:

```
IP_NEXTHOP_SENTINEL = '255.255.255.255'
class IP(models.Model):
    nexthop = models.IPAddressField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=IP_NEXTHOP_SENTINEL,
        help_text='Use %s to indicate no next-hop' % IP_NEXTHOP_SENTINEL
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ## hack for Django #5622 (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5622)
        if self.nexthop and self.nexthop == IP_NEXTHOP_SENTINEL:
            self.nexthop = None
```

Overview:

Creation of `IP` objects outside of the admin portal works as intended, which is why I kept the `null=True` argument on the `nexthop` field. The only place where 255.255.255.255 would ever be set as the next-hop would be through the admin portal, so I decided that overloading `save()` to always replace the sentinel with `None` would give me the final result I desire and it doesn't really feel too much like a hack.

Thanks for your input on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can convince the devs to accept one of the patches, I'd say just run a patched copy of Django until the patched version lands. If not, then it might be less headache to just use a sentinel value, as you suggested, even though it is a hack. You might also just use a regular `CharField` instead of an `IPAddressField`, but then you get stuck having to maintain validation logic on your own.

Comment: Yeah, using a `CharField` would be more of a hack than just using a sentinel value.  Using a patched version of Django would be a higher cost due to maintaining a branch in our package management system.  Now, to make friends with a Django dev?  That has appeal!

Comment: Getting the devs to accept one of the patches does seem to be the ideal fix, and then you only have to handle a patched version of Django for a little while. As for package management, `virtualenv` and `pip` seem to be a better fit for most web applications, so you can use the specific version of Django you need without impacting other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using `blank=True` for `nexthop`, rather than both `blank=True` and `null=True`? As noted in the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null):

> Only use null=True for non-string fields such as integers, booleans and dates.

Comment: (Whoops, deleted my comment.) Yes, I have tried everything pretty much, however I have to pass `blank=True` so the admin portal does not consider this a required field.  I must use `null=True` because the PostgreSQL `inet` column requires the field to be `NULL` if it is going to be empty.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Sorry -- I misunderstood the problem before.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate you taking the time to post a response. :)

Answer (score 0):

And what about using **empty string** as sentinel, instead of 255.255.255.255 ?

As admin back-end stores empty field as empty string (when `blank=true`), this solution has the advantage to be transparent for the user and doesn't force him to use a faked value...